# unable to view / load firebase analytics with a specific google account (with project editer access)

Tags: google-workspace, firebase-console

I have a Firebase project with both android and iOS Apps. and have two developers with editors access to the project.I am able to view analytics console with android dev's account but when I tried with iOS dev's account its showing an error **"analytics.google.com refused to connect."**

I found some blogs where mentioned to clear browsing history, cookies and remove firewall like protection things , but I found it unrelated to my problem cause its happening only for one user.

I observe that the android dev's account is a normal gmail account(ex@gmail.com) where I am able to view analytics dashboard and other parts but iOS dev's account is a GSuite account(ex@company.co.in) where I got this error.
But with both account I am able to view database and storage things.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GSuit, you may have to request admin of your GSuit to view Google Analytics. By default, it is disabled for every account.

For more details:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6304816